# Install a package to PyPI

Tags: python, pip

I went through a tutorial to show me how to install a Python package that I developed to PyPI, so it could be installed by pip. Everything seemed to work great, but after installing with pip, I get an error trying to use the library. Here is a transcript:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install pinyin_utils                                                                           Collecting pinyin_utils
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/26/95b2d80eae03dfe7698e9e5a83b49f75e769895a4e0bb8048a42c18c7109/pinyin_utils-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pinyin-utils
Successfully installed pinyin-utils-0.1.0
C:\WINDOWS\system32> python                                                                                             Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pinyin_utils import convertPinyin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pinyin_utils'
>>>
```

On Windows 10, Python 3.7.4

Comment: I found my local packages folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages) and found a subfolder named pinyin_utils-0.1.0.dist-info, but no file or folder named pinyin_utils (yes, I installed this package globally, in a PowerShell window with admin privileges)

Comment: Please don't add info to your own questions using comments. Also, please provide some info about your package (setup.py content for example) and how you have packaged and uploaded it to PyPi

Answer (score 0):

Your `setup.py` doesn't include code into the package. As `pinyin_utils.py` is a file it perhaps meant to be a top-level module. Add `py_modules` to your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    …
    py_modules=['pinyin_utils'],
    …
)
```

PS. Also I recommend to add your `setup.py` to [the repository](https://github.com/johndeighan/pinyin_utils).

Comment: Thank you. I was relying on using "packages = find_packages()" and my understanding that the __init__.py file was no longer required in Python 3.7. Perhaps it's what find_packages() uses. My case is so simple that it's probably better to not rely on find_packages(). I've removed the module from PypI since it didn't work as is, will review the docs for setup.py, then add it back with a slightly incremented version number.

Comment: I still can't get this to work (I'm using the test server now). The file uploads to the test server. It bothers me that I can't simply view the files there, but need to download them to view them, but the pinyin_utils.py file is in the .tar.gz file when I download it. Next, I try to install using pip, specifying the PyPI test server. That tells me that it worked, and if I try to install again, it tells me that it's already installed. But, python won't import it.

Comment: In my site-packages folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages) I see a folder named pinyin_utils-0.1.2.dist-info, but no folder named pinyin_utils. I don't see a way to attach a file here, so I'll include my setup.py file in the following comment and hope it isn't too long ;-(

Comment: setup(
 name = "pinyin_utils",
 version = "0.1.3",
 author = "John Deighan",
 author_email = "john.deighan@gmail.com",
 description = "Utilities for handling Chinese pinyin",
 long_description = README,
 long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
 license="MIT",

 url = "https://github.com/johndeighan/pinyin_utils",
 packages = find_packages(),
 py_modules = ['pinyin_utils'],
 classifiers = [
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
  "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
  "Operating System :: OS Independent",
  ],
 python_requires = '>=3.6',
 )

Comment: "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" - ??? Anyway, it seems to be working now. Because of the character limitation, I removed the line "install_requires = []," which I assumed simply meant that my library has no dependencies. Aparently.. don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **pypinyin** package onece.

```
pip install pypinyin
```

Latest version available today is **0.44.0**

It works well with Python3x and Python2

Please follow the below syntax to get proper output.

```
>>> from pypinyin import pinyin, lazy_pinyin, Style
>>> pinyin('中心')  # or pinyin(['中心'])
[['zhōng'], ['xīn']]
```